# sedの処理を追えるようデバッグプリントを出したい

Tags: sed

sedのコマンドを理解したいと思うのですが、パターンスペースやホールドスペースに入力されコマンドで加工されていく様子を、コマンド説明と想像だけではなかなか把握しづらく思っています。

パターンスペースやホールドスペースに何が保持されていて、コマンドによってどう変わっていくのかを、いっそのことsedのソースコードにデバッグプリントを仕込むとかして、見える化して観察できんものかと思っているのですが、既にそういうアプローチでsedの解説をされている記事をご存知の方がおられましたら教えて頂けませんでしょうか？

現状は以下を紐解いているところです。
http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/sed/sed-4.4.tar.xz

Answer (score 4):

デバッグプリントとは少し違いますが、[sedsed](https://github.com/aureliojargas/sedsed)でパターンスペースやホールドスペースを逐次表示できます。

```
$ echo $'a\nb\nc' | sedsed.py --debug -ne '1!G;$p;h'
PATT:a$
HOLD:$
COMM:1 !G
PATT:a$
HOLD:$
COMM:$ p
PATT:a$
HOLD:$
COMM:h
PATT:a$
HOLD:a$
PATT:b$
HOLD:a$
COMM:1 !G
PATT:b\na$
HOLD:a$
COMM:$ p
PATT:b\na$
HOLD:a$
COMM:h
PATT:b\na$
HOLD:b\na$
PATT:c$
HOLD:b\na$
COMM:1 !G
PATT:c\nb\na$
HOLD:b\na$
COMM:$ p
c
b
a
PATT:c\nb\na$
HOLD:b\na$
COMM:h
PATT:c\nb\na$
HOLD:c\nb\na$
```